# Online Status Report of a FTP Server?

Tags: html, ftp, reporting, status

I want to make a status report of when my FTP server is on and when its off. HTML is the language which I prefer to use. I have never used HTML before, and I need it due to a  large request of when my ftp server is off and when its on.

Comment: You'll need to elaborate.  What do you mean by "when my FTP server is on and when its off".  Do you mean you have scheduled down time and want to advertise that on your web somewhere?  Or do you mean you want to monitor when it goes down unexpectedly, and comes back up?

Comment: yea, when ur not able to connect to it, and when you are able.

Comment: This can be closed based on the official close reason of "_Too Broad: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer._

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing this, I would write an ASPNET page (or PHP, or etc) that simply connects and authenticates to the FTP server.  If this succeeds, the server is online.  The ASPX logic would then generate an HTML page indicating the results.

In the simple case you connect to the FTP server with each request for the page.  It should cache the result though, and only check every minute, or five minutes, or some longer interval, regardless of how often a request for the status is made.

Answer (score 1):

May i suggest instead of writing your own, you just install server monitoring tools on your server instead? It might be an easier choice that writing your own.

[Google search](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=server+monitoring&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

HTML is a static markup language. You might want need to use a server-side script like PHP or Perl to query for the FTP server status.